# Update Query Efficiency

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to run an update statement in Oracle 11g using the below query.  Usually it works just fine.  This time, the statement is taking an overly long time to run.  I've run this with up to 150 million rows in each table before.  This time I have 189 million rows in both tables and it is really struggling.  I've tried creating indexes to help things run faster.  Recid is unique, and the same for each table.

```
UPDATE QP24784_tab1_Strip1 A SET NoConflict_600_Flg = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM QP24784_tab1_Strip_NC1 B
  WHERE A.zip = B.zip AND A.lname = B.lname AND A.fname = B.fname
  AND noconflict_600_rn > 1);
```

Table QP24784_tab1_Strip_NC1 is a subset of columns from QP24784_tab1_Strip1, but the nonconflict_600_rn flag is created.  The purpose of this process is to create a flag where there is no conflict with other records-  no conflict means there are no other records that have the same name and zip code.  The noconflict_600_rn is created over the rows using the row_number function, and any records that have a row_number higher than 1 means that there's a conflict.  Then I add that flag back to the main table by joining on name and zip.

For the life of me, I can't seem to think of a way to make this run more efficiently.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Recid is unique? but you do not use it in your query. post also exec plan. Anti-joins are problematic by definition, sometimes there is no way how to optimise them. Can you create unique/nounique index on QP24784_tab1_Strip_NC1(zip, lname, fname, noconflict_600_rn). But even if you create that index Oracle might decide to put the whole table QP24784_tab1_Strip_NC1 into a hash segment in TEMP tablespace and then run full table scan over QP24784_tab1_Strip1.

Comment: Also when you notice that you do know more about the data, then optimizer does you might help him by using cardinality hint.

Comment: I think all those explain plans will not help you on the number of rows you are dealing with. You need to run updates in batches, e.g. run your update for the number of rows and commit. Then run your code again... This technique described in Tom Kyte Effective Oracle by Design book, if I remember this correctly. In one of the chapters he describes the exact steps on how to deal with great number of rows and run your queries effectively. I can try to look it up if do not forget. I think you can download this book.

Comment: I'm confused by "The noconflict_600_rn is created over the rows using the row_number function".  Does that mean this is not the full query?  If so, can you post the entire query?  Also it might help to post the explain plan like this: first run `explain plan for update ...;` and then run `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  Depending on the number of rows matched it may help to use a `MERGE` instead of an `UPDATE`, since a `MERGE` can use hash joins.  Also, try using `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'your sql_id', type=>'text') from dual;` to find out why it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting all the IDs that you want to set to 1 in a temp table, then updating from that table. Oracle tends to like that sort of approach.

At the end of the day, I've ended up having to do horrible cursor based updates when updating millions of records in Oracle.